# -T option in perl

Tags: perl

What is the `-T` flag in Perl used for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It enables "taint mode," a dataflow analysis that prevents potentially unsafe operations using untrusted inputs.

For example, it might seem reasonable to store a new user's details with

```
open my $fh, ">", "/var/myservice/$username"
  or die "...";
print $fh ...;
```

To illustrate how this is useful, what if a malicious user gives a username of `../../../etc/passwd` and your service runs as root?

Taint mode won't allow the code above to run if the value of `$username` came from the command line or as a CGI form parameter.

The [`perlsec`](http://p3rl.org/sec) documentation shows how to "untaint" untrusted inputs to be sure they're safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
-T  | Forces "taint" checks to be turned on so you can test them.
```

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uperl.htm

See also [Is Perl's taint mode useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228457/is-perls-taint-mode-useful) and [CGI/Perl Taint Mode FAQ](http://gunther.web66.com/FAQS/taintmode.html).

Thanks, Google!

Answer (score 0):

If taint mode is on, you have to untaint data with a function, such as applying a regular expression to remove unsafe characters.