# Writing post data to a file using CGI-perl

Tags: perl, cgi, server

I was working on client program in pure html/javascript which would be able to send the folder, file and its contents as paramaters in a post request to the target cgi script (i.e saveFile.cgi ).

I am able to retrieve the data from the post request , but i am unable to create a file/folder using these form data in the script, yet i am able to print these values using print.

Also, I am able to create file/folder using the exact string literal which I was trying to retrieve from the post request.I am not understanding where i am going wrong.

I am programming in a windows environment:

Client Code :

```
var data = {
             "folder": variant,
             "file"  : "metadata.json",
             "content": response
           };

           $.post('../cgi-bin/demos/saveJSON.cgi', data, function(resp) {
                  // Do something with the request
           }, 'json');
```

Server-Side/CGI Script:

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe -wT
    use CGI;
    use JSON;

    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

    $query = new CGI;

    $folder  = $query->param("folder");
    $file    = $query->param("file");
    $content = $query->param("content");

    #print "Folder " . $folder ."<br/>";
    #print "File " . $file ."<br/>";
    #print "Content " . $content ."<br/>";

    mkdir($folder, 0700) unless(-d $folder);
    open(OS,">$folder/$file") or die("Cannot write to file");
    print OS $content;
    close(OS);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the cgi method `param` to retrieve the data?

Comment: @JE SUIS CHARLIE Its another option to retrieve the data, I know but even that did not help my case.

Comment: You should always test the result of  `open`.

Comment: The added a die statement , to check is open was successful. Also mkdir $folder is not successful but mkdir "myFolder" is even though $folder = query->param('folder').

Answer (score 1):

> i am unable to create a file/folder using these form data in the
>   script, yet i am able to print these values using print

Almost certainly, the problem is that your web server doesn't have permissions to create a file in the directory where you are trying to create it. You can check that theory by improving the error checking for the `open()` call and looking in the web server error log.

```
# $! contains the details of the error
open(OS,">$folder/$file") or die("Cannot write to file '$folder/$file': $!");
```

You'll then have to change your processing so that you're writing to a directory where you have the correct permissions.

Some other suggestions.

- Always include `use strict` and `use warnings`.
- Use `my $query = CGI->new` rather than `$query = new CGI`.
- Use lexical filehandles and three arguments to `open()`

  - `open my $os_fh, '>', "$folder/$file" or die "..."`
- Consider moving away from CGI to a modern solution like [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/).

Comment: If the filename/folder was part of a string literal the folders/files get created perfectly but same thing doesn't work with POST params. These params are printing right but I am unable to use them to create a file while the string literal way works.I don't understand this hypocrisy.

Comment: Then I can only reiterate my suggestion about the enhanced error logging around the call to `open()`. Try that and then update your post with details of what you get in the error log. There must be some weird characters getting into your parameters.

Comment: Nailed it. It was all due to the "taint or -T" flag set for the perl command. This prevented it from executing variables received from form data. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239076/t-option-in-perl

Comment: So, once you improved your error logging, you immediately saw what the problem was?

Comment: I do always check the apache/logs/error.txt but didn't pay much attention to -T flag thing because the error was not very specific to this issue and the above link , supplemented the theory about "taint". Anyways thanks :) for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether you can install modules on your server. If yes, I would definitely advise you to use some abstraction layer like IO::All.

```
...
$folder  = $query->param("folder");
$file    = $query->param("file");
$content = $query->param("content");

# very minimal folder and filename sanitizing: allow only 
# alphanumeric characters. No slashes!
$folder =~ s{[^a-z0-9_\-.]}{}gi;
$file   =~ s{[^a-z0-9_\-.]}{}gi;

use IO::All;
io( $folder )->mkdir;
io( "$folder/$file" ) < $content; # yes, the < is like "put into"
```

The cool thing about IO::All is that is hides the handling of file handles, buffers and such and will die with an error when something goes wrong - like when the directory cannot be created.

See: [IO::All on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-All/lib/IO/All.pod)

The sanitizing is very minimal and does not allow for subdirctories, but you don't want anybody to write send something like

```
{ 
    folder:  "/var/www-data/.evil", 
    file:    "hacker.zip",
    content: "..someting really evil.."
}
```

to upload this to your server.

Anyhow, to install IO::All use either

```
cpan IO::All
```

or on Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libio-all-perl
```

Comment: None of this will help solve the actual problem. Which almost certainly comes down to file permissions.